# Deshabilitar un checkbox de la misma fila

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox

Tengo realizado una tabla que contiene dos columnas de checkbox que representan una condición: SI y NO.

[image: ImagenTabla]

Cada checkbox es un objeto que va formando un array según lo que se vaya seleccionando. La propiedad "Condición" del objeto en un inicio es null pero lo edito según el checkbox que escoga. Lo que deseo hacer es deshabilitar el primer checkbox o el segundo, según lo que seleccione, para evitar que se pueda seleccionar dos condiciones en una misma fila. Pensé en recorrer la columna pasando también el index mediante el evento change pero no comprendo como podría hacerlo.

El HTML que tengo:

```
<form [formGroup]="demoFormGroup" (ngSubmit)="submit()" style="margin-top:50px; margin-bottom:30px">
    <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>SI</th>
                <th>NO</th>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngFor="let x of data; let i = index">
                <td>{{x.Descripcion}}</td>
                <td>
                    <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" (change)="onChange1($event,i)" [value]="x"
                        [disabled]="selected">
                    </mat-checkbox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" (change)="onChange2($event,i)" [value]="x"
                        [disabled]="selected">
                    </mat-checkbox>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <br><button>Submit</button>
</form>
<pre>{{ demoFormGroup.value | json }}</pre>
```

Y el .TS

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormArray, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  demoFormGroup: FormGroup;
  data: any;
  selected: false;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.demoFormGroup = this.fb.group({
      info: this.fb.array([])
    });

    setTimeout(res => {
      this.data = [
        {
          Id: 4,
          Descripcion: 'Opcion 1',
          Condicion: null
        },
        {
          Id: 6,
          Descripcion: 'Opción 2',
          Condicion: null
        },
        {
          Id: 10,
          Descripcion: 'Opción 3',
          Condicion: null
        }
      ];
    });
  }
  onChange1(event, i) {
    const x = (<FormArray>this.demoFormGroup.get('info')) as FormArray;
    event.source.value.Condicion = 1;
    this.onEventChecked(event, x);
  }
  onChange2(event) {
    const y = (<FormArray>this.demoFormGroup.get('info')) as FormArray;
    event.source.value.Condicion = 2;
    this.onEventChecked(event, y);
  }
  onEventChecked(event, ctrl) {
    if (event.checked) {
      ctrl.push(new FormControl(event.source.value));
    } else {
      const i = ctrl.controls.findIndex(
        (x: any) => x.value === event.source.value
      );
      ctrl.removeAt(i);
    }
  }
  submit() {
    console.log(this.demoFormGroup.value);
  }
}
```

La demo la subí a stackblitz [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hrtkcz)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo se necesita una función `onChange()`, como parámetro recibe el objeto actual en la iteración y un valor booleano indicando si se activará o se desactivará.

Adicional a eso el estado `checked` del checkbox dependerá de lo siguiente:

`[checked]="x.Condicion"` si `Condicion` es verdadero entonces el checkbox se marca.

`[checked]="x.Condicion != null && !x.Condicion"` Si `Condicion`  no es `null` y tiene un valor `false` entonces el checkbox no se marca.

Si `Condicion` está con su valor inicial `null` ambos checkbox estarán desmarcados.

---

```
<td>
    <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" (change)="onChange(x,true)" [checked]="x.Condicion" [disabled]="selected">
    </mat-checkbox>
</td>
<td>
    <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" (change)="onChange(x,false)" [checked]="x.Condicion != null && !x.Condicion"
        [disabled]="selected">
    </mat-checkbox>
</td>
```

---

La función `onChange()` queda así:

```
onChange(option : any, enabled : boolean) {
    option.Condicion = enabled
  }
```

Solo asigna el valor recibido a la propiedad `Condicion`.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kurmrz?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)